# Error when setting borders in macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am running a macro that sets the format of a group of cells.

```
Public LastRow as Integer
Sub Formatting()
    LastRow = 20
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A15:" & "AA" & LastRow)
        .Borders.Weight = xlThin
    End With
End Sub
```

When I run the macro the first time it works but on the second time I receive the following error
Run-time error '1004':
Unable to set the Weight property of the Borders class.

Also I am unable to manually change the borders of the effected cells now. I'm not sure what is happening. I am running excel 2010

Thanks in advance,

Comment: that error pops because your sheet is protected. Check any other code that might be protecting your sheet.  For example, any procedure inside Worksheet_Change, Worksheet_Calculate or similar that could be triggered automatically after you run the procedure the first time and protects the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Few Things

1. Do not use a `Function` for this. Use a `Sub`. You use a `Function` when you want to return something
2. Fully Qualify your variables/Objects
3. I don't see you setting the value of `LastRow` anywhere.

Try this

```
Sub Formatting()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = 20

    '~~> Change Sheet1 to the relevant sheetname or use Code Name
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A15:" & "AA" & LastRow)
        .Borders.Weight = xlThin
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I ran your code and it works the first time but I get the same error the second time that I run it. Also LastRow is a public integer set in another part of the macro. I have edited my original post to make that clearer

Comment: `1` From the updated code, I still see that you haven't taken into consideration the first two suggestions that I mentioned :) `2` Also at runtime, debug the code and see what is the value of `LastRow`

Comment: I have updated the code, run it twice and the same problem remains. I run the same code in a new workbook and it works fine. The problem must be created somewhere else in the code, but this sub is the only routine that does any format changes

Comment: Would it be possible for us to see the Excel file?

Comment: The updated code works, so it must be something outside of the code you have shown that causes the error.